# create additional jar when building war

Tags: java, gradle

I have a dependency in my gradle build script:

```
apply plugin 'war'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.jsimone:webapp-runner:7.0.22'
}
```

when creating a war, is there way a task createWebappRunnerJar could create a jar from given remote sources?

I was looking at http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html but I don't think it was meant to be used for remote sources.

The webapp-runner is built into the war, maybe there's a way to copy it out of the war somehow, if it can't be built from remote sources?

In maven the following does the same:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                        <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                        <version>7.0.22</version>
                        <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: maybe I could create a separate build script just for the jar and then run the script from my main build.gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to create a separate configuration just for the dependencies you intend to include as remote sources and then create a copy task that copies that configuration to the location of your choice.

```
configurations {
    remoteSources {
        transitive false
    }
}

dependencies {
    remoteSources 'com.github.jsimone:webapp-runner:7.0.22'
}

task copyRemoteSources(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.remoteSources
    into "${project.buildDir}/remoteSources"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, I ran a quick test this morning and looks like this is exactly what I need. I will accept your answer as soon as I get to take this baby out for a testrun later tonight. Thanks!